# Use Markov inequality to prove that a positive random variable is null a.s

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

I would like to show that if the expectation of a positive random variable $X$ (integrable) is $0$ then $X$ is null almost surely.

I thought on a proof and would like to know if it is correct, it uses the Markov inequality.

We have for all $\varepsilon>0$

$$
\mathbb{P}(X>\varepsilon) = 0
$$

This implies that $\mathbb{P}(X> 0) = 0$. Indeed, suppose it is not the case, then there exists a set in which $X(\omega)>0$ with nonzero probability. This means that we can find an $\eta>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X>\eta)\neq 0$. But this is not possible using Markov inequality with $\varepsilon=\eta$.

Thus we conclude that $\mathbb{P}(X> 0) = 0$ and since $X$ is non negative we get

$$
\mathbb{P}(X =0) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X>0) = 1
$$

Is this correct and if not what can I improve please ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: $P(X>0)=\lim_kP(X>1/k)=0$ due to continuity of measures

Comment: @Snoop Thank you for this remark it is more efficient indeed ! But what about my argument is it false ?